# Approximation for $ e^{ - x^2 } $ , x>0.

Tags: probability, logarithms, approximation

what is the good approximate so that it works for a large range of values.
My purpose is to calculate logarithm of likelihood ratios.

$
\log \left( {\frac{{e^{ - x_1 ^2 }  + e^{ - x_3 ^2 } }}
{{e^{ - x_2 ^2 }  + e^{ - x_4 ^2 } }}} \right)
$.
I am going to calculate with the help of MATLAB. so doesn't matter how complex it gets.

Comment: What kind of approximation do you want? Polynomial?

Comment: Is there difficulty in calculating with $ e^{- x^2 } $ ? PDFs are easy to calculate.Polynomials are not easier either.

Comment: the problem is when the value of x is large,

Comment: as large as 300.

Comment: The problem is when two of the x s are very large, and two of the xs are very small.

Comment: @Wojowu will try every possible approximation. The polynomial approximation which you were saying about, please could you describe it?

Comment: You can try Taylor expansion. I don't know how complicated nor how efficient it is.

Comment: but the Taylor expansion is valid only if 0 < x < 1.

Comment: There is no obvious global expansion.  But, check out the answer I posted.  It splits the problem into two cases.  One for which $x_1$ and $x_2$ are large, but $x_2>>x_1$.  The other for which $x_1$ and $x_2$ are still large, but $x_2-x_1$ is "small" in some sense.

Answer (score 1):

First, write $$\log\left(\frac{e^{-x_1^2}+e^{-x_2^2}}{e^{-x_4^2}+e^{-x_1^4}}\right)=\log\left(e^{-x_1^2}+e^{-x_2^2}\right)-\log\left(e^{-x_1^2}+e^{-x_2^2}\right)$$Let's focus on either term, say the first one.  Then, write $$\log\left(e^{-x_1^2}+e^{-x_2^2}\right)=-x_1^2+\log \left(1+e^{-(x_2^2-x_1^2)}\right)$$  We will examine two cases.

---

**Case 1**:
Assume that $x_2>> x_1$ and $x_2$ is "large" in some sense.  Then,
$$\log \left(1+e^{-(x_2^2-x_1^2)}\right)=O(e^{-(x_2^2-x_1^2)})$$and
$$\log\left(e^{-x_1^2}+e^{-x_2^2}\right)=-x_1^2+O(e^{-(x_2^2-x_1^2)})$$which is approximately $-x_1^2$ for large $x_2$ and $x_2>>x_1$.

---

**Case 2**:
Assume that $x_2>x_1$, but $x_1$ and $x_2$ are "close" in some sense. Let $t=x_2^2-x_1^2$.  Then, we have
$$\log \left(1+e^{-t}\right)=\log\left(1+1-t+\frac12 t^2+O(t^3)\right)$$
$$=\log(2)+\log\left(1-\frac12 t+\frac14 t^2+O(t^3)\right)$$
$$=\log(2)-\frac12 t +\frac18 t^2 +O(t^3)$$ 
$$=\log(2)-\frac12 (x_2^2-x_1^2)+\frac18 (x_2^2-x_1^2)^2+O\left((x_2^2-x_1^2)^3\right)$$
Thus, $$\log\left(e^{-x_1^2}+e^{-x_2^2}\right)=\log(2)-\frac12 (x_2^2+x_1^2)+\frac18 (x_2^2-x_1^2)^2+O\left((x_2^2-x_1^2)^3\right)$$